# Finding a homeomorphism between two topological subspaces X and Y

Tags: general-topology

So I have two topological subspaces on euclidean plane:

$X=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R^2}|x>0,y>0\}$

$Y=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R^2}|-x-1<y<0,x<0\}$

And i need to find an homeomorphism between them two.

So for $x$ seems $h(x)=-x$ could be okay, but i don't know where i should map y.

I would be grateful for any effort.

Comment: $x<00$ ? One zero is usually enough, now it looks like you actually meant $100$ or something.. So what is it?

Comment: Maybe $x<\infty$ ;)

Comment: it's one 0 only, i clicked to hard i guess

Answer (score 2):

First, you should draw a picture of the sets.

[image]

You see, that $Y$ is a part of the open unit ball wrt the norm $\|(x,y)\|=|x|+|y|$. Therefore, you have to reflect $x$ and $y$ and scale them such that it fit. You can do it the with 
$$h(x,y)=\frac1{\|(x,y)\|+1}(-x,-y)=\left(\frac{-x}{x+y+1},\frac{-y}{x+y+1}\right).$$

But you still need to prove that this $h$ is a homeomorphism between $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: That $(-x,-y)$ means it is a vector function right?

Comment: Since $X, Y\subseteq\mathbb R^2$, the homeomorphism $h: X\to Y$ has to map vectors to vectors...

Comment: I guess the absolute value bars are redundant, given the domain...